# Coded image to background of div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set background of div using coded image, it is adding black background to div but it is showing in css when i inspected it chrome.

Here is javascript code.

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
var imgPath = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/service/file/download/hd1.jpg?code=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjU3ZTYwOTMyOWE5MmQ0MGEwNzk5YzZmYiJ9.H78qRMZNOfWxVnA8mbybQD5Yh1ZBVRhRQgzFNmJMVvs";
$(myDiv).css("background-image", "url(" + imagPath + ")");
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: do you have a typo in line 3? "imagPath" should be "imgPath"

Comment: Is the question how to put in a background image or how to prevent someone from being able to see the image in an inspector? Or was that a typo as well "but it is showing in css when i inspected it in chrome"?

Comment: it is some sort of encrypted path, when i paste that path in img tag then is shows image in that tag, and when i paste that coded url in browser, it downloads image with respected image name which is before ?code

Comment: actually it is generated from server side to hide actual image path same like facebook does.

Comment: css("background-image", "url('" + imagPath + "')"); try this it will work

Comment: it is showing black background to div, but image in viewed when i inspect it and checked css

Answer (score 0):

so the background-image doesn't work with css function. If you do

```
    $(myDiv).css("background")
```

you will get all the background related properties as a string separated by space
like "background-repeat-property background-image-property" what you can do is store this string as a variable and concat it with url(imagePath) string and in css function set the background property to the above concanated string so the above code will be

```
    var backgroundString = $(myDiv).css("background")
    var urlString = "url("+imagePath+")"
    backgroundString = backgroundString+urlString
    $(myDiv).css("background",backgroundString)
```

This works well if you have no background-image but if you have a background-image you have to replace the existing url part with regex.

```
    var backgroundString = $(myDiv).css("background").replace(/url\(\"(http)(s)+\:\/\/\w+.+/,'')
```

Comment: i do appreciate your efforts, but is is still showing black background of that div.

Comment: try to put that in a function in  setTimeout